# How do I inject reference types in a table view cell and reload the row of the said cell without causing a memory leak?

Tags: uitableview

For instance, executing the following code, in which a stepper is injected in a table view cell and the cell is reloaded when the user changes the stepper's value, causes the memory usage to grow pretty quickly (I stopped the simulation at 1GB) when you tap on the stepper.

Also the CPU usage jumps straight at 99%, and the UI freezes.

Note: I'd like to know exactly what I asked, not how to make a table view cell with a stepper in general.

I know that calling reloadData() or reconfigureRows(at:) doesn't cause any of the mentioned issues.

Also please don't reply with questions like "Have you tried to use weak references?".

The code is short: please reply with a working solution if you can.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let tableView = UITableView()
    let stepper = UIStepper()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
        stepper.addTarget(self, action: #selector(stepperValueChanged), for: .valueChanged)
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
        tableView.frame = view.bounds
    }
    
    @objc private func stepperValueChanged() {
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.accessoryView = stepper
        var configuration = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
        configuration.text = "\(stepper.value)"
        cell.contentConfiguration = configuration
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: My question was answered on https://developer.apple.com/forums//thread/747718?login=true&page=1#781754022.